Can you legally shield your assets by pretending to transfer them to someone else?
Consider the following hypothetical:
Let's say Bob is worried his personal assets might be put at legal risk in the near future. Maybe someone's about to sue him for breach of contract, maybe he feels the IRS has a reason to come after him, etc.
So Bob goes to Alice, and they sign a document in which Bob transfers legal ownership of some of his assets (real estate, cars, stocks, money, etc.) to Alice, in exchange for having access to them for some period of time.
Now, we have two possible scenarios:

The risk vanishes -- perhaps Bob wins his case. In this case, they scrap the document as if nothing happened.

The risk materializes, and Bob's assets are ordered to be seized. In this case, Bob goes to court and presents the document proving that he in fact is not the owner of those assets. Let's say the authenticity & timestamp of the document are incontrovertibly provable -- perhaps with, say, cryptography.


Let's say for the sake of question that no other party is aware of what's going on. Only Alice and Bob are aware of the document, and they both agree on its contents.
The first question is: In what circumstances will a court deem the agreement valid?
And the follow-up question is:

If the answer is "always": then isn't this a really easy way to dodge the legal system?

If the answer is "sometimes": is there a source explaining when/what actions render different types of agreement valid?

If the answer is "never": why, and what would it take to make it valid?



I'd recommend googling for "fraudulent conveyance," "fraudulent transfer," and "Voidable Transactions Act."

Isn't this essentially what "trusts" are for? Instead of giving your assets to Alice, you put them in the trust, and make Alice the executor.

making it valid would take not trying to scam the system.  Smart crooks have tried this for years and we have pretty much worked out how to prevent it.

Related: https://xkcd.com/1494/

(USA:) I think the true answer can only be "it depends". For some purposes, in some cases, for some structures of transaction and not others, if you have good lawyers: things that generally look like this can work. There are also a lot of cases in which it won't, and it will be very fact- and jurisdiction-dependent. Bankruptcy has its own special-case rules for what past transactions can be reversed. Medicare has its own rules. Divorce has its own rules (different per state.) And so on.

If a normal person would say "that sounds like a scam": don't do it unless a good lawyer says it won't get you in trouble with the court. Courts don't like shenanigans.

there is nothing to stop Alice from afterwards saying "why should I give all that stuff back? You gave it to me and now it's mine". If Bob's such a shady character as to consider such a scheme, it's likely Alice is no different after all.

Is that a gift? A loan? A sale for very low price? In many cases there are tax implications as well.

@jwenting In real life scenarios it's common for people to use their spouses, children, parents etc. to try to hide assets in this way, so the the risk of them refusing to return them is, while not zero, lower than for some mere acquaintance.

@JBentley There are families, and there are families...

You may find the Selling Chametz tag on J.SE to be interesting.  This hasn't made its way to secular law.  However, it wouldn't shock me if this someday became relevant in Israel, given that the Israeli government does care about Chametz.

Is it legal in the US to just "transfer" assets to other people? Aren't there taxes to pay? In Franc for instance you can give up to 100k€/15 years to your children tax-free but for unrelated people gifting is expensive.

@WoJ Yes, there are gift taxes, but they only kick in after you exceed a threshold. Currently you can give $18K per year per recipient (and double it for a married couple). So if you have lots to shelter, you might need to recruit Alice, Cathy, Diane, etc. into your scheme. There's no difference for children.

I recall some purveyor of such schemes suggesting that such agreements need to be entered into way before trouble was on the horizon in order to be (legally) effective.

I can't tell if this is influenced by current events, but I have a sneaking suspicion that Rudy Giuliani is also interested in the answer to this question. "A federal judge on Tuesday ordered the former New York City mayor to appear in court ...to explain why he allegedly "secreted away" his property and failed to transfer anything into the custody of former election workers ...as he was ordered to do last month to fulfill a $148 million judgment."

LLCs exist... They don't protect your assets from certain types of criminal proceedings Or if you treat your LLC like a private piggy bank. And they require forethought. But frankly anyone who is doing business that can have a breach of contract large enough to cause them financial difficulties should be operating an LLC anyways.

@Questor Limiting liability (which an LLC does much less effectively than you suggest) is a distinct matter from transferring assets to reduce liability. And, if an insolvent LLC transfers assets to its owners as distributions or to others without substantially equivalent value, those are fraudulent transfers too.

@bdb484 -- not to mention "clawback", which is exactly what it sounds like.

united-states
Every U.S. jurisdiction has some version of the Uniform Fraudulent Transfers Act which provides a variety of remedies when this is attempted, although different versions of it have been enacted in different states since not every U.S. state has updated its statutes to the latest version.
Some U.S. jurisdictions have, in addition to some version of the Uniform Fraudulent Transfers Act, a separate statute or common law doctrine that self-settled trusts (i.e. those funded by someone who is later a debtor in which the debtor has some possibility of benefitting from the trust assets) are void ab initio with respect to claims of the debtor's creditors, no matter how much time elapses from the funding of the trust. This is subject to a statutory exemption from creditors for legally allowed contributions to tax favored retirement accounts like a 401(k), pension, or IRA.
If Bob is in bankruptcy, Title 11 of the United States Code (the bankruptcy code) also contains its own fraudulent transfer statute applicable to bankruptcy cases only, in addition to continuing to make the relevant state law remedy still available to a bankruptcy estate trying to claw back assets for general creditors. Furthermore, if a debtor in bankruptcy has engaged in a generally fraudulent course of conduct rather than just isolated instances of fraudulent conduct, a bankruptcy discharged can be completely denied to the debtor.
While not all fraudulent transfers that can be clawed back have to be made with an intent to defraud creditors, when that intent is present, common law fraud claim and criminal fraud charges are also available as remedies.
If such a transfer has been made and it has the effect of harming a spouse in a divorce, this is covered by the "economic waste" doctrine, which can be used to adjust property divisions or make alimony awards to balance the harm caused by the fraudulent transfer. Alimony awards, moreover, can't be discharged in bankruptcy.
If a transfer is made in an arrangement which the debtors claims that the debtor can't control, but the court issuing the judgment doesn't believe that the debtor is being truthful, the court can order that the debtor be incarcerated indefinitely until the asset in question is paid over, for contempt of court.
If property is subject to a lien (e.g. a tax lien, or a mechanic's lien, or a Uniform Commercial Code security interest, or a mortgage) before it is transferred, the lien remains in effect against collateral for the debt it secured, even if the collateral is transferred to someone (pretty much, no matter who receives the transferred property). The rules for determining whether the lien was in effect and valid before a transfer is made are often quite technical and tricky in practice.

In what circumstances will a court deem the agreement valid?

If the statute of limitations for seeking a particular remedy for a fraudulent transfer expires before legal action is taken.
Under the Uniform Act, the statute of limitations is usually four years, although there is some state to state variation. In the case of transfers that are fraudulent as a matter of law (usually because they involve a transfer of property without a substantially equivalent  exchange of value while the debtor is insolvent), this statute of limitations usually runs from the date that the transfer becomes possible to discover from publicly available information. In the case of transfers that are made with an actual intent to defraud a creditor (including a particular foreseen future creditor), then the statute of limitations usually runs from the date that the fraudulent transfer is discovered by the creditor.
In bankruptcy, the deadline for seeking a clawback is governed by within the case deadlines for completing various steps of the bankruptcy process and usually has to be raised no later that the Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 60(b) deadline for setting aside a civil judgment due to newly discovered evidence, that begins to run after the case is close and discharge is granted.
The deadlines are similar in divorce cases (involving divorce case deadlines and deadlines for setting aside divorce judgments based upon new evidence under the relevant state rules of civil procedure).
The deadline for suing for common law fraud varies considerably from state to state and tends to usually begins to run on the date that the fraud is discovered or should have been discovered with reasonable diligence.
The death of the debtor also established additional jurisdictional deadlines for seeking non-criminal remedies from the debtor. But, even if, for example, Bob died and the deadline for bringing civil claims against him expired before the defrauded creditor took action against Bob, relief could still be sought from Alice.
The deadline for bringing criminal prosecutions for fraud varies greatly between jurisdictions. The death of the debtor prevents criminal prosecutions from being brought and terminates any pending criminal cases.
Footnote regarding foreign asset protection trusts
Most non-U.S. jurisdictions that are popular places to locate asset protection trusts allow fraudulent transfer actions to be brought, but have short statutes of limitations to do so, high procedural barriers to bringing lawsuits of this kind, and crabbed interpretations of the substantive grounds for awarding relief when a fraudulent transfer lawsuit is commenced in a timely fashion and the procedural barriers are overcome.
But if a foreign asset protection trust is invested in assets that are subject to the jurisdiction of a U.S. court, the U.S. court will often disregard the laws of the jurisdiction where the foreign asset protection trust is formed or administered and instead may treat the assets in the name of the foreign asset protection trust as if they were owned by the debtor who contributed those assets to the trust instead.
Contempt of court sanctions are frequently imposed on debtors who transfer assets to a foreign asset protection trust, when the debtor claims that the debtor is unable to control the assets of the trust and the current assets of the trust are beyond the jurisdiction of the court.

There is another exception to the self-settled trust rule for court authorized trusts for the benefit of minors that are often created in connection with a personal injury settlement in favor of the minor (e.g., in connection with the wrongful death of a parent).

Wow this is a super comprehensive and fascinating answer. Thank you!

I think the "this is a crime" part is somewhat too hidden ;). It's no better than hiding the assets in your garden.

@DonQuiKong Worse in many cases, since transferring many of these assets will create a public record. At least when you stuff wads of cash in your freezer, you don't go down to the county recorder's office to tell them about it.

To offer some historical perspective, this is one of those things in human behavior that appear to not change through millennia.
In the Law Code of Gortyn (Ancient Crete around 450 B.C.), we read

If anyone owing money or being the loser in a suit or while a suit is being tried should give anything away, the gift shall be invalid, if the rest of the property should not be equal to the obligation.

If lawmakers of the era felt the need to include that in the code, most likely the behavior had already been observed.
The Code has been published in Willetts, R. F. (Ed.). (1967). The Law Code of Gortyn. de Gruyter, from where I took the translation.

This doesn't really apply to my scenario though, because the agreement would've been made before the suit started.

@user541686 The implicit assertion here is that the punitive measure at the end of the trial is effectively backdated to the time of the crime, not the time of the ruling. If I steal money on Jan 1st, give some away to Bob on Jan 5th, and get convicted of theft and ordered to pay back what I stole on Jan 10th, then the fine that I pay is counted against my financial state on Jan 1st, and will (if needed) invalidate any gifts I gave out afterwards, specifically to prevent the abuse that you're pointing out. Any gift I gave Bob Dec 25th would not apply, as it predates the crime on Jan 1st.

@user541686 This is actually not as implicit as I initially interpreted it. The quoted text specifically includes "give anything away [..] while a suit is being tried", which indicates that it's not the date of the ruling that is relevant here.

and in Dutch law at least it's worse as criminal asset forfeiture can reach back way beyond the date of the crime you'd being investigated for. That Mercedes you bought 2 years ago can be seized if the investigators assume (and that's a very loose definition) it might have been purchased from the proceeds of other crimes (e.g. based on your known income at the time of purchase being "too low to afford such luxury", another very loose criterium)

@user541686 I would say that the provision is not predicated on a suit. It says "If anyone owing money...should give anything away, the gift shall be invalid".  So if Bob became a debtor in 446 B.C. (and this could somehow be proven), then the creditor bringing a suit during 444 B.C. claiming the house that Bob gifted away in 445 B.C., could argue that Bob, while already owing the creditor money gave away his only property, so the gift should be invalid. At least this is what my lawyer friends are telling me, since I am not.

england-and-wales
I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "in exchange for having access to them for some period of time". I'll therefore offer two answers based on two different interpretations of what you have written.
Bob has the right to take back the assets
In this case, although Bob doesn't own the assets directly, he owns something of equal value; the right to take them back. The court can simply assign that right to the claimant. Or, if the contract prevents assignment, it can order Bob to exercise the right himself and then pay the claimant.
Bob has no right to take back the assets
In this case, the contract with Alice is a "transaction at an undervalue" for the purposes of Section 339(3)(c) of the Insolvency Act 1986 which provides:

For the purposes of this section and sections 341 and 342, an
individual enters into a transaction with a person at an undervalue if
[...] he enters into a transaction with that person for a
consideration the value of which, in money or money’s worth, is
significantly less than the value, in money or money’s worth, of the
consideration provided by the individual.

This provision is triggered because Bob transfers his assets to Alice without receiving back something of similar value.
If the claimant then applies to make Bob bankrupt (because he lacks the means to pay the claimant), various other provisions of the Act will take effect.
Section 339(1):

[...] where an individual is made bankrupt and he has at a relevant
time (defined in section 341) entered into a transaction with any
person at an undervalue, the trustee of the bankrupt’s estate may
apply to the court for an order under this section.

Section 339(2):

The court shall, on such an application, make such order as it thinks
fit for restoring the position to what it would have been if that
individual had not entered into that transaction.

Sections 341(1) - (3) provide that the "relevant time" is 2 years prior to the date of the bankruptcy application. This can be extended to 5 years where Bob was insolvent either immediately before or after the transaction. Insolvent means that Bob is either unable to pay his debts as they fall due (income insolvency), or has liabilities which exceed his assets (capital insolvency).
The effect of all of the above is that within 2 years of Bob entering into the contract with Alice (in any event) or within 5 years (if Bob was insolvent), the claimant can apply to make Bob bankrupt and then ask the court to order Alice to repay Bob's assets.
If the answer is "always": then isn't this a really easy way to dodge the legal system?
In either scenario, there is nothing to prevent the contract between Bob and Alice being "legally effective". The parties are free to enter into such a contract if they wish and, if they correctly follow the formalities of contract formation, it will be a legally binding contract between them. This means that Bob can be potentially at risk of being sued by Alice for breach of contract if the claimant recovers the assets (since she no longer has the assets which Bob promised to give her). However, given that in this scenario Bob has been made bankrupt and Alice's assets were required to pay his debts, it's unlikely Alice would recover anything.
So the answer is no, this isn't an easy way for Bob to dodge his obligations.

For cases where "the value of which, in money or money’s worth, is significantly less than the value, in money or money’s worth, of the consideration provided by the individual" how would a court determine the actual value? Theoretically Alice could give Bob some weird monkey cartoon and they could claim it's worth half a million dollars, but I doubt that would hold up? How are these kinds of shenanigans avoided?

@barbecue Alice/Bob would offer up whatever evidence they have of the cartoon's value and the "trier of fact" (judge or jury) would decide accordingly. If that "evidence" is just their say-so, it probably won't go well!

@TripeHound What if Alice and Bob could produce previous examples where someone else paid a huge amount for a similar monkey cartoon? I'm thinking of EFT type scenarios. Is there a "sanity check" of some sort a judge could rely on?

@barbecue Then the person seeking the money would produce an expert to say that, although in some cases similar images might be worth a lot of money, in this case it is not. It would be up to the trier of fact to decide how much weight to put on that expert's testimony vs. Alice + Bob + their expert's. It's not uncommon for a trial to hinge on which of two expert witnesses is more convincing.

@barbecue It's similar to what would happen in the US if the IRS audited you and decided you needed to pay gift tax when giving someone the NFT (I assume that's what you meant when you wrote EFT -- the latter are easy to value).

@barbecue Also, if you say one of the assets isn't worth much, then the creditor who is coming after you will simply demand more of your other assets, in order to get the full amount you owe them. So unless you undervalue everything, there's little point. And in that case, there's no point in transfering the assets in the first place -- either way, they'll take everything.

@barbecue Remember that to get to the point where undervalued transactions are being considered, there has been both a bankruptcy and a failure to settle the liabilities with the bankrupt's assets. That means that we've reached a point where the creditor has already taken and sold the NFT, so its real value is no longer in dispute. Either the NFT was worth what is being claimed, in which case it has been used to satisfy the debt, or it wasn't, and then we're back to reversing the undervalued transaction.

"I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "in exchange for having access to them for some period of time"" Suppose I sell you my car, but you agree that I get to keep using it for the next 4 weeks. It's yours, legally speaking, but you're okay with taking physical ownership at a later stage.

@Flater Yes, but the OP referred to money being part of the assets, and it's not clear to me how you can differentiate between the right to "use" money for 4 weeks and the right to take it back; it's the same thing. Hence I didn't want to assume that mere usage was what OP meant. If it's as your describing then a mere right of usage for 4 weeks is going to be far less valuable than the assets, so we're in the undervalued transaction scenario.
